# Build UITabBarController under UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have clean first page without UITabBarController , and UINavigationController is hidden , so  when user went to second page , it will need UITabBarController with few tabs , so my question is how can i build a UITabBarController without make it rootViewController ..

in AppDelegate.m

```
MainViewController *mainviewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainviewController];
[nav setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

in MainViewController.m after button get clicked

```
ShowViewController *showView = [ShowViewController new];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:showView animated:YES];
```

in ShowViewController.m

```
UIViewController *tm1 = [UIViewController new];
tm1.title = @"tm1";
tm1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIViewController *tm2 = [UIViewController new];
tm2.title = @"tm2";

UIViewController *tm3 = [UIViewController new];
tm3.title = @"tm3";

NSArray *tm = @[tm1,tm2,tm3];

UITabBarController *tabbarC = [UITabBarController new];
[tabbarC setViewControllers:tm animated:YES];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:tabbarC animated:YES];
```

tabbarC didn't show .. xcode said : 2014-02-03 01:07:48.205 zhui002[45992:70b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2014-02-03 01:07:48.355 zhui002[45992:70b] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .

so could anyone tell me is that possible to use UITabBarController to build what i want , or i should build it with UIButton and make it looks like tabbar ?

thx !

Answer (score 1):

The error Xcode is throwing most likely means you are trying to begin an animation before the previous animation has completed. You could try setting the animation property to NO in both the pushViewController calls to avoid getting the error.

A more elegant way to do what you are trying to do is make the ShowViewController a subclass of UITabBarController and set your tabs in viewDidLoad

Comment: thanks a lot ! after i set animated:NO , tab bar show up ! here are some other problems:
1. Back Button : So i guess i should reset the whole button to make it back to MainViewController directly . now it seems i push two times to get tab bar to show.
2. animated : now there is no animated from MainViewController to ShowViewController , two animated set , all of them have to be NO, so is there any way to show next view with animated to make it looks good ?
3. is there any other way to do this ?
thanks !

Comment: i put tab bar codes to viewDidLoad , and replace [[self navigationController] pushViewController:tabbarC animated:NO] with [[self navigationController] addChildViewController:tabbarC] , but still , if i set [self.navigationController pushViewController:showView animated:YES] , there will be no tab bar show .. but if i set animated:NO then it’s ok .. how should i fix it ? thanks!

Comment: Regarding your second comment, I don't see see why you would need to use the addChildViewController to add the UITabBarController. You should instead make UITabBarController the superclass for ShowViewController.

Comment: How should i do that ?

Comment: In ShowViewController.h change :UIViewController to :UITabBarController. Also read up on inheritance for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes you can. Hook up your TabBarController as a segue for 2nd ViewController. It will still be a part of the navigation controller.

Comment: Thx, how should i do that ?